# Dependency Injection in Spring MVC web-application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, dependency-injection

I am trying to understand how to do DI in a web-application based on Spring MVC framework.

For this, I modified the **web.xml**.

```
<web-app ...>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Then, I created **spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">

    <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.example.hellocontroller.HelloController"/>

    <bean id="simpleUtil" class="com.example.util.SimpleUtil"/> ----->(1)

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The below is the controller class:

```
public class HelloController extends AbstractController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleUtil simpleUtil; -------> (2)

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("calling the method add(a,b) ");

        simpleUtil.add(2, 3);

        ModelAndView modelandview = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        modelandview.addObject("welcomeMessage", "first Spring MVC Application");
        return modelandview;
    }
}
```

In spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml I am defining various beans, in particular at (1) --> `<bean name="simpleUtil" class="com.example.util.SimpleUtil"/>`

Now, in the controller I want this bean to be injected by Spring framework as listed at (2):

```
    @Autowired
    private SimpleUtil simpleUtil;
```

When I run this program I am getting NullPointerException, meaning that Spring didn't injected the dependency.

Is there something wrong I am doing here? How to make this work?

I have few related questions here:

Q1) Does `spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml` serve as bean definition configuration file? If not, then where do I provide the bean definition files which I want to be managed by Spring?

Q2) How does Spring MVC's front-controller gets to know what bean id of Handling Mapping is? (in our case the ID given is "HandlingMapping").

Answer (score 1):

yes `spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml` serve as bean definition configuration file for that you need to add listener in spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml here is the code u need to add in ur  `spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

now in application-config.xml u can do ur DI
for controller config u need to add one more xml file 
for complete example check my login example of spring in github